# How can I integrate the design of LibreOffice 5.2.0.4 into Ubuntu Unity

Tags: libreoffice

The latest update of LO to version 5.2.0.4 does no longer integrate into my Ubuntu Unity desktop.

What package do I need to install to re-integrate it?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Same issue here and looks like we need to wait for an update, I installed it from the ppa. No issues on Arch Gnome yet.

Comment: @ArupRoyChowdhury should we report this as a bug somewhere?

Comment: Update to latest from libreoffice ppa, all fixed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to install libreoffice-gnome package via Synaptic.

Comment: This package was missing on my system. Thank you!

Comment: I seem to be missing another package. Please have a look at my [screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/iUQuuhF.png). Do you have any idea what package I am missing?

Comment: Seems to be a shared problem: http://disq.us/p/1atzgnw

Answer (score 2):

You can work-around by installing Libreoffice 5.2 via snap:

```
sudo snap install --channel=beta libreoffice
```

Then you can run it via

```
/snap/bin/libreoffice
```

I tried this, works fine.

Comment: Thanks! So, it's a problem that has been fixed in the latest Beta version?

Comment: Not really, snap is different way to get software - let's say standalone packages with all dependencies within. When you updated by adding libreoffice ppa and doing apt update, you were forced to uninstall libreoffice-gtk package (dependencies hell) and it is why LO looks like in times of Windows 95. IMHO it is almost always better to wait, than install something from PPA.